# Adding Annotation from Property List - use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations, property-list, undeclared-identifier

I am trying to add an annotation from property list. I found a solution here:

> [Xcode Annotation from Property List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437578/xcode-annotation-from-property-list)

but it gives me an error "**use of undeclared identifier "racks"**" and "**use of undeclared identifier "GetRacks"**" here:

```
   // Add annotations
    NSArray *bikePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *bikeDocumentsDirectory = [bikePath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [bikeDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    NSDictionary* bikesDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    GetRacks racks = [[GetRacks alloc] initWithDictionary:bikesDictionary];

    for(RackAnnotation *rackAnnotation in [racks getRacks])
    {
        [mapView addAnnotation:rackAnnotation];
    }
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not initialize

```
GetRacks racks
```

when racks is not a pointer.

```
GetRacks * racks = [[GetRacks alloc] initWithDictionary:bikesDictionary];
```

is gonna work just fine!

EDIT:
change this:

```
GetRacks racks = [[GetRacks alloc] initWithDictionary:bikesDictionary];
```

to this:

```
GetRacks * racks = [[GetRacks alloc] initWithDictionary:bikesDictionary];
```

Comment: This menas GetRack is not defined. Where have you defined it?

Comment: how can I define it? sorry, I am a newbie. I just followed this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437578/xcode-annotation-from-property-list

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish!? What is GetRacks, and what is it supposed to do? The guy in that thread has a class called GetRack, that is why he can do it.

Comment: I need to add Pins to my map from plist file. nothing more

Comment: You need to learn some more objective-c before going further. The reason why NSString *string works, is because objective-c has a class called NSString. You can't just write whatever you want. If you want to write GetRack * racks, you have to make a class called GetRack. If you only want maps, read this: http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/ - and then post questions that has relevance. Good luck!

Comment: I've read it before, but I need an example with map and plist file. But thanks for spending time!

Comment: Are you mixing the pList with something else? the plist is the information file of your app. Is the list initialized in your code?

Comment: I mean a property list file that store a data

Comment: Can you please show me the code? Or the list or whatever. I really don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5

Comment: Follow that tutorial, that'll be enough... That is showing you how you can get the XML file importer to a NSArray. Then use that other guys method, and you'll be fine.